# Driving a small motor: What's needed?

Tags: motor

This question is very basic, but I'd like to ask it anyway.

I need to drive a [small motor](http://www.velleman.eu/distributor/products/view/?id=375874). I'm thinking about connecting it directly to 4 AA batteries and using a simple switch. Is there anything else needed?

Also, it its datasheet unit gcm is mentioned. What is it? I thought that torque is measured in N*m or similar units.

Comment: I remember pulling a DC motor from a toy when I was young and hooking it up to the speaker output on my dad's stereo - It didn't drive (obviously in retrospect) but you could hear the Beatles playing through oscillations in the motor :)

Comment: @Peter Gibson  I am sooo going to try that!

Comment: make sure you use your _Dad's_ stereo then!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gcm is gram * centimeters. The stall torque is listed as 340 gcm. This means that if you stuck a pulley with a radius of 1 cm on the shaft, wrapped a string around it, and tied it to some weights, it would fail to lift more than 340 grams.

Your strategy of 4 AA batteries and a switch will probably work. If the system involved digital electronics, you'd want to add a diode in parallel with the motor to prevent voltage spikes when you opened the switch. (Google "flyback diode.") You'd also want a capacitor in parallel with the motor to filter out high-frequency electrical noise, which would scramble the rest of your circuitry. But for a small motor and a mechanical switch, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning to control the motor with a microcontroller (e.g. Arduino) you may need to have a look at using MOSFETs to switch the motor on and off.

A good introductory description, including a video, of motor control can be found [here](http://www.nerdkits.com/videos/motors_and_microcontrollers_101/).